# Salesforce to Salesforce connection invitation email not being sent

Tags: salesforce-to-salesforce

I am trying to configure Salesforce to Salesforce following the steps mentioned in this blog https://blog.skyvia.com/salesforce-to-salesforce-integration/

When I am trying to send invitation for connection after the Contact is created I am not receiving any connection email.

No success on the doing the following:

- I set the orgs email deliverability to **All email**
- Checked the spam
- Changed the email address

Below is the snapshot of the configuration:

[image]

Comment: Can you check if 'Activate bounce management' and 'Return Bounced emails to sender' are disabled under Setup-->Deliverability ?  Also check [troubleshoot email delivery](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386389&type=1)

Comment: Where you able to get it to work?